# Datetime null 01/01/0001 - Erro na seleção (Winforms+Camadas bll,dal,model) C#

Tags: c#

Fiz uma regra de negócio onde eu passo algumas informações da minha ordem de serviço para o meu caixa. Porém quando vou realizar a busca no caixa, minha data passa 01/01/0001, e da erro de caracteres.

```
    Public List<Model.caixa> Select()
    {

        List<Model.caixa> ListaCaixa = new List<Model.caixa>();

        SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection(strCon);

        string sql = "Select * from caixa;";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conexao);

        conexao.Open();

        try

        {
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Model.caixa caixa = new Model.caixa();
                caixa.CodCaixa = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0].ToString());
                caixa.CodSrv = Convert.ToInt32(reader["CodSrv"].ToString());
                caixa.TipoSrv = reader["TipoSrv"].ToString();
                **caixa.DataPagamento = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["DataPagamento"].ToString());**
                caixa.Status = reader["Status"].ToString();
                caixa.Parcelamento = reader["Parcelamento"].ToString();
                caixa.Pagamento = reader["Pagamento"].ToString();
                ListaCaixa.Add(caixa);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Deu erro na seleção do caixa!");
        }
        finally
        {
            conexao.Close();
        }
        return ListaCaixa;
    }
```

Quando chega  `caixa.DataPagamento = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["DataPagamento"].ToString());` já cai pro `catch`.

Se alguém puder ajudar, ficarei grato!

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente o seu `reader["DataPagamento"]` é nulo e você está chamando um método de uma instância nula o que causa uma exceção.

Faça esta alteração:

```
if(reader["DataPagamento"]!=null)
   caixa.DataPagamento = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["DataPagamento"].ToString());
```

Comment: a primeira leitura no banco deu certo, porém na outra já entra no catch.

Comment: Qual é o exception que está dando? insere na frente do catch isso: `(Exception ex)` e pegue o que tem na propriedade ex.Message

Comment: ex.Message "Cadeia de caracteres não foi reconhecida como DateTime válido." string - essa ai

Comment: O problema está na formatação da sua string de data no banco, você consegue ver qual é o formato que está no banco?

Comment: coloquei DateTime

Comment: Pegue um texto da coluna DataPagamento pra eu poder fazer um teste com o formato salvo

Comment: De preferencia o que está dando erro

Comment: uma pergunta, onde eu pego esse texto pra ti? estou em debug com ele, se me falar o local já mando

Comment: No debug, selecione `reader["DataPagamento"]` e clique com botão direito e selecione a opção `Add Watch`

Comment: Ou então você vê direto no BD

Comment: reader["DataPagamento"] error CS0103: The name 'reader' does not exist in the current context

Comment: foi essa mensagem de erro que apareceu

Comment: Você vai precisar por um pause break nele e mandar pesquisar ai vai dar certo

Comment: ta certo, vou fazer isso amanhã te falo o resultado abraços